# No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were valid for the specified scheme

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xcode-bots

My integration bot when trying to run the app on the server complains that...

`xcodebuild: error: No destinations were specified with the -destination flag which were valid for the specified scheme 'MyScheme'.`

Not sure how to approach this error?

Prior to crashing it does a bunch of searches for different devices...

`2014-05-21 14:14:22.631 xcodebuild[49977:100b] [MT] DVTDeviceSearch: Searching for device with type 'iOS Simulator', options: {
    OS = "7.1";
    name = iPad;
}, genericOnly: NO allowMultiple:NO timeout:0.000000
2014-05-21 14:14:23.134 xcodebuild[49977:100b] [MT] DVTDeviceSearch: Search found devices: (
    "<DVTiPhoneSimulator: 0x7ff6fdb9a230> {\n\t\tsessionActive:              NO\n\t\tlaunchService:              (null)\n\t\tlaunchSucceeded:            NO\n\t\tcurrentSimulatorSession:    (null)\n\t\tdidExitRecursionGuard:      NO\n\t\tdeviceInfo:                 <DeviceInfo iPad>\n\t\tsimulatedSystemRoot:        <DTiPhoneSimulatorSystemRoot 0x7ff6fdb8e6f0> path=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.1.sdk version=7.1 name=Simulator - iOS 7.1\n\t\tsimulatedDeviceFamily:      2\n\t\tsupportedDeviceFamilies:      (\n    1,\n    2\n)\n\t\t}"
)`

Checking the servers xcode I can see 6.1 and 7.0 simulator installed.

It also runs fine from xcode.

Answer (score 1):

Your log states it is looking for 7.1 simulators, not 7.0.  Either install 7.1 simulators to your Xcode server or downgrade your Deployment Target to 7.0.

Answer (score 1):

I had to update my Xcode Version on our build server.

You can also check, which simulators are available, when you go to 
`Xcode`-> `Preferences...` -> `Components`

Make sure the given SDK version was available here. In your case it would be `iOS 7.1 simulator`. If it was not available, hit the download button.